# How to create general tag for all textview URL's?

Tags: android, html, url, hyperlink, textview

I have a textview, which contains an amazon URL. I am able to make this work with the full URL, and it will open the link in the browser.

However, I do not want the entire URL in the textview, I want to replace it with the text 'Buy'. I want the textview to be set to BUY for all links.

I have seen questions where each textview and URL are fixed individually. But not generally for all. I tried this - http://jtomlinson.blogspot.co.uk/2010/03/textview-and-html.html - and I managed to set the text to 'Buy' but it was no longer a a clickable link.

Just to give some more info. In my app, I parse an xml into a database, and a search will return results in a listview containing textviews.

Here is my code for the onclicklistener:

```
 myList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                // Get the cursor, positioned to the corresponding row in the result set
                Cursor cursor = (Cursor) myList.getItemAtPosition(position);

                //fix this line. modify string value
                // String searchValue = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("searchValue"));
                String author = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("author"));
                String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("title"));
                String price = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("price"));
                String publish_date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("date"));
                String description = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("description"));
                String module = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("module"));
                String buy = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("buy"));

                //Check if the Layout already exists
                LinearLayout bookLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.customerLayout);
                if(bookLayout == null){
                    //Inflate the Customer Information Vie
                    LinearLayout xbookLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.Layout);

                    View book = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.book_info, xbookLayout, false);
                    xbookLayout.addView(book);
                }

                //Get References to the TextViews
                authorText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.xauthor);
                titleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.xtitle);
                priceText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.xprice);
                publishDateText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.xpublish_date);
                descriptionText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.xdescription);
                moduleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.xmodule);
                buyText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.xbuy);

                // Update the parent class's TextView
                authorText.setText(author);
                titleText.setText(title);
                priceText.setText(price);
                publishDateText.setText(publish_date);
                descriptionText.setText(description);
                moduleText.setText(module);
                buyText.setText(buy);


                searchView.setQuery("",true);
```

Comment: If you have the position of the item in the list ( in OnItemClick)  then just invoke a cursor and getString for "buy" again..Like you do in getView.  Better call it "url".

Comment: and then? that can't be it

also currently my link is clickable via this code in the xml

   android:clickable="true"
            android:autoLink="all"/>

Comment: You don't need a link. Your textview is clickable if you have set an on item click listener on the list view. So if the item is clicked extrackt the according url and hand over to the browser.

Comment: Sorry but i'm just not understanding what you are trying to say. 

I can my links to click and work fine. But that is only from the plain URL's stored on my database. I'm wanting to replace every URL which will be placed in the buyText textview with the text 'Buy'.

Comment: You can place 'Buy' in every textview you want. That text does not matter. In on click handler you get position and you can get the url for that position. Then start a browser. I dont see your problem.

Comment: `String buy = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("buy"));`. Until now you did not tell what the content on String buy becomes. I suppose it is the url you are talking about. Thats why i suggested to change that to "url".

Comment: Thank you. What you said was correct. Sorry for the lack of understanding,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed to set the setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()) to textview,without it textview will not be able to open the link.Do it like

```
    TextView tv =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    String url ="http://jtomlinson.blogspot.co.uk/2010/03/textview-and-html.html";
    String htmltext ="<a href ="+url+">BUY</a>";
    tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmltext));
```

Note : Keep in mind that you have internet permission.

Comment: This does makes sense. Though I don't think it applies exactly to what I want.

In your code, you have String url. However, I do not want to put in the String URL for each textview. I have an XML file with a large number of different urls, which appear in my textview.

What I want to do, is ahve the buyText textview to always be set as Buy for whatever the URL is. I hope this makes some sense

Comment: To add further. Basically the buyText textview appears a number of times in my listview. The URL's are all retrieved from my database. I want every URL to be placed in the buyText texview and I want the textview text to be 'buy'.

Comment: Well thats exactly what you get here. (If it works).

Comment: You should bind the url to textview in your list adapter inside getView() method not in the list item click listener.